# Is it OK to use Android's built-in SQLite storage for concurrent data storage?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm writing an Android application, which will consist of

1. background service 1, which reads sensor values in regular intervals (e. g. every five minutes the program reads sensor values for 30 seconds, during the measurement period values are read twice per second),
2. background service 2, which analyzes the sensor values and calculates some metrics from them,
3. background service 3, which runs once in 3-7 days and removes old data from the database (both sensor values and metrics) and
4. a GUI activity, which shows some of the sensor values and/or metrics, if the user opens the application and presses some button.

There will be 2 tables - `SensorData` and `Metrics`. Background service 1 will write to `SensorData`. Background service 2 will read from `SensorData` and write to `Metrics`. Background service 3 will remove rows from both tables. The GUI activity will read from both tables.

I was thinking about how to implement a threadsafe storage for the sensor values and metrics.

An obvious solution is to use the built-in SQLite database.

I have following questions:

1. Is it safe to use in this setting?
2. Will Android's SQLite handle writing of two numeric values (`long` and `double`) twice per second?
3. Does it support concurrent access (what happens, when the GUI activity issues a query on `SensorData` and background service 1 tries to write into the same table simultaneously) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. by using the `SQLiteOpenHelper` as a singleton, you are thread-safe. `SQLiteOpenHelper` handles the locking of the sqlite database (which is the sqlite mechanism to handle concurrent reads/writes).
2. This is something to test. but, generally speaking, do you need to write to the database that often?. you can cache the data in memory and flush them to the database at a slower rate.
3. the short answer is 'yes it supports concurrent access'. for details, review this [sqlite document](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html), android sqlite is just a wrapper on this. you can configure it to behave the way you find suitable after reading this document.